# Colocar ordem alfabética crescente a descrição, quando o resultado vem de uma pesquisa através de campo numérico

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Tenho agora uma dúvida, como colocar a relação de funcionários de um determinado **código de função** em ordem alfabética crescente.

Vou colocar o código abaixo:

```
                       <table align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td id="centro">Selecione Gerente</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="centro">
                                    <select name="txtgerente" id="txtgerente" >
                                        <?php
                                            $query_gerente = "SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE colab_funcao in($cod_ger,$cod_gerjr) ORDER BY CAST(colab_nome_venda AS UNSIGNED) ASC";
                                            $result_gerente = mysqli_query($con, $query_gerente) or die(mysqli_error());
                                            while ($row_gerente = mysqli_fetch_array($result_gerente)) {
                                                echo("<option value='".$row_gerente['colab_id']."'>".$row_gerente['colab_nome_venda']."</option>");
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

O campo colab_funcao é varchar(3).
Nele está o código da função do funcionário.

O que eu quero é que apareça a relação dos nomes dos funcionários que têm a função determinada, mas que estivessem em ordem alfabética.

Mais uma vez, obrigado a todos pela atenção e ajuda.

Comment: Pelo que pude entender: `SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE colab_funcao in($cod_ger,$cod_gerjr) ORDER BY colab_funcao ASC, colab_nome_venda ASC;`.

Comment: Não funcionou, continua a mostrar desordenado.
Obrigado pela ajuda...

Comment: Qual é o campo que contém o nome do funcionário?

Comment: colab_nome_venda

Comment: Consegui. Uma coisa muito simples e não conseguia enxergar. Ficou assim:

$query_gerente = "SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE colab_funcao in($cod_ger,$cod_gerjr) ORDER BY colab_nome_venda ASC";

Comment: Tudo bem que você conseguiu atender a sua necessidade, mas note que em sua pergunta você diz: "como colocar a relação de funcionários de um determinado código de função em ordem alfabética crescente" e não apenas todos os funcionários em ordem alfabética crescente.

Comment: Não eram todos os funcionários em ordem alfabética crescente.
Eu tinha primeiro que selecionar os funcionários que fossem das funções $cod_ger e $cod_gerjr. E depois dessa seleção, colocar os que foram selecionados em ordem alfabética crescente.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Clériston Melo !
Tenta mudar o seu select para ver se funciona, tenta com esse select abaixo:

SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE colab_funcao in($cod_ger,$cod_gerjr) ORDER BY colab_nome_venda DESC

Comment: Opa Guilherme, obrigado pela ajuda, mas não funcionou, continua mostrando de forma desordenada.
Na verdade, mostra em ordem numérica crescente(pelo código do funcionário).

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO

Ficou assim:

```
$query_gerente = "SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE colab_funcao in($cod_ger,$cod_gerjr) ORDER BY colab_nome_venda
```

Tão simples, e eu complicando.
Obrigado a todos mais uma vez, pela atenção e ajuda...